# Examples of different biblatex entry types?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I was wondering what some `biblatex` entry types are used for. In the [Overleaf documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex) there is a list of avalible entry types:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| article | book | mvbook |
| inbook | bookinbook | suppbook |
| booklet | collection | mvcollection |
| incollection | suppcollection | manual |
| misc | online | patent |
| periodical | suppperiodical | proceedings |
| mvproceedings | inproceedings | reference |
| mvreference | inreference | report |
| set | thesis | unpublished |
| custom | conference | electronic |
| masterthesis | phdthesis | techreport |
| datatype |  |  |

Specificually I wonder what the enry `datatype` is used for? What are the mandatory and optional fields for this entry? I am also uncertain what `set` is used for. I would also like to know if there is a difference between `misc` and `custom`?

I also found some additional entries that is defined by `biblatex` but are not well supported according to [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management).

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| @artwork | @audio | @image |
| @movie | @music | @performance |
| @video | @software |  |

And some legal entry types:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| @commentary | @jurisdiction | @legislation |
| @legal | @letter | @review |
| @standard |  |  |

I am also curious about some of these. What is `standard` used for? What fields does `music` and `performance` accept? Do you put the music composer as `author` in that case? For instance; how would you go about citing music by Beethoven using `music`? I suspect it is not that different from using the `misc` entry?

Finally it would be very useful with some kind of list of what fields are mandatory and optional for each entry. I really liked the list provided by wikibooks:

[image]

Unfortuantley it does not include the two latter tables nor all entries from the first. Another shortcoming is that you *can*, for exaple, provide the `url` field for `masterthesis` or `phdthesis` and have it appear in the bibliography. This is however not mentioned by the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (specifically §2 *Database Guide*) has a short description of each entry type supported by the standard `biblatex` data model. It also lists the fields supported in each type and has a short explanation for each field.

The documentation does not have many example entries, but `biblatex` comes with the file [`biblatex-examples.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib) that has example entries for many types and shows a lot of `biblatex` features.

While third-party lists can be useful, they may not always be completely accurate. Specifically, `@datatype` is not actually a type supported by the standard `biblatex` data model, instead it appears to be a typo for `@dataset`, a type for digital data sets (see more about the history of `@dataset` https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/880).

Comment: The biblatex-examples.bib does not contain any examples of the additional entries.